# Asihttprequest 61 errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

I'm using the `ASIhttprequest` in many projects but recently with each new project when I'm trying to add the `ASIhttprequest` classes I get the following error before using classes just when I'm trying to import them:

Build finjan of project finjan with configuration Debug

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/finjan.app/finjan normal i386
cd /Users/Apple/Desktop/application/finjan
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk -L/Users/Apple/Desktop/application/finjan/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Apple/Desktop/application/finjan/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Apple/Desktop/application/finjan/build/finjan.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/finjan.build/Objects-normal/i386/finjan.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -o /Users/Apple/Desktop/application/finjan/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/finjan.app/finjan

Undefined symbols:
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationIsValid", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageApplyCredentialDictionary", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest applyAuthorizationHeader] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest applyAuthorizationHeader] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest applyProxyCredentials:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest applyCredentials:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageIsHeaderComplete", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedData:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFStreamSSLCertificates", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamSSLCertificates$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamSSLCertificates$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest proxiesForURL:fromPAC:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFProxyTypeKey", referenced from:
      _kCFProxyTypeKey$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFProxyTypeKey$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFProxyPortNumberKey", referenced from:
      _kCFProxyPortNumberKey$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFProxyPortNumberKey$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      _kUTTagClassMIMEType$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kUTTagClassMIMEType$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedData:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedData:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFProxyAutoConfigurationURLKey", referenced from:
      _kCFProxyAutoConfigurationURLKey$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFProxyAutoConfigurationURLKey$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationRequiresUserNameAndPassword", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFHTTPAuthenticationUsername", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationUsername$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPAuthenticationUsername$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort$non_lazy_ptr, _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost$non_lazy_ptr , _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy$non_lazy_ptr )
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPMessageGetResponseStatusCode", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFProxyTypeHTTP", referenced from:
      _kCFProxyTypeHTTP$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFProxyTypeHTTP$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic$non_lazy_ptr in ASIAuthenticationDialog.o
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isReachable] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isConnectionRequired] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isConnectionOnDemand] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isInterventionRequired] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isReachableViaWWAN] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isReachableViaWiFi] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability reachabilityFlags] in Reachability.o
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressData:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest proxiesForURL:fromPAC:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest main] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest checkRequestStatus] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFProxyTypeSOCKS", referenced from:
      _kCFProxyTypeSOCKS$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFProxyTypeSOCKS$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPAttemptPersistentConnection", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPAttemptPersistentConnection$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPAttemptPersistentConnection$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopyVersion", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationCopyRealm", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest main] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFProxyHostNameKey", referenced from:
      _kCFProxyHostNameKey$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFProxyHostNameKey$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopyResponseStatusLine", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPRequestBytesWrittenCount", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPRequestBytesWrittenCount$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPRequestBytesWrittenCount$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressData:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
  "_kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork", referenced from:
      _kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationCreateFromResponse", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressData:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      +[ASIHTTPRequest compressDataFromSource:toDestination:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeNTLM", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeNTLM$non_lazy_ptr in ASIAuthenticationDialog.o
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeNTLM$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeNTLM$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationCopyMethod", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kCFHTTPAuthenticationAccountDomain", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationAccountDomain$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPAuthenticationAccountDomain$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFHTTPAuthenticationRequiresAccountDomain", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest findProxyCredentials] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest findCredentials] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_kCFHTTPAuthenticationPassword", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPAuthenticationPassword$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPAuthenticationPassword$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFHTTPVersion1_0", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPVersion1_0$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPVersion1_0$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFHTTPVersion1_1", referenced from:
      _kCFHTTPVersion1_1$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFHTTPVersion1_1$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      _kUTTagClassFilenameExtension$non_lazy_ptr in ASIHTTPRequest.o
     (maybe you meant: _kUTTagClassFilenameExtension$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

More specifically, it requires CFNetwork, SystemConfiguration, MobileCoreServices, and lib (libz.tbd for iOS 9).

Edit: It also needs libxml2

Comment: sorry, but CoreGraphics is not needed.

Comment: On iOS 9.0 I added libz.tbd and it got rid of this error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Just to put some documentation on this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

just remember to include the lixml file path in the "Header Search Paths" section of the project configuration. which is usually /usr/include/libxml2 that did the trick for me.